# Add header to the table

Tags: tables, pdftex

I want to create the table as follows in latex. Note, the table below is created using excel.

[image]

So, far I have created something like this:

```
    Observed-modeled |observed-modeled| Observed-modeled |observed-modeled|
Min.          -1.5360000          0.0001891          -2.3740           0.001259
1st Qu.        0.0002512          0.1633000          -1.2280           0.674700
Median         0.3593000          0.5390000          -0.6202           1.101000
Mean           0.8554000          1.0020000          -0.2094           1.085000
3rd Qu.        1.6470000          1.6470000           0.7418           1.413000
Max.           5.5370000          5.5370000           5.0530           5.053000
```

The code for the above table is as follows:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
  \hline
 & Observed-modeled & $|$observed-modeled$|$ & Observed-modeled & $|$observed-modeled$|$ \\ 
  \hline
Min. & -1.54 & 0.00 & -2.37 & 0.00 \\ 
  1st Qu. & 0.00 & 0.16 & -1.23 & 0.67 \\ 
  Median & 0.36 & 0.54 & -0.62 & 1.10 \\ 
  Mean & 0.86 & 1.00 & -0.21 & 1.08 \\ 
  3rd Qu. & 1.65 & 1.65 & 0.74 & 1.41 \\ 
  Max. & 5.54 & 5.54 & 5.05 & 5.05 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

How can I tweak the code so that I can add header `Station T1` and `Station T2` as shown in figure above ?

The minimal working code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations}
\usepackage[top=0.5in,bottom=1in,left=0.5in,right=0.4in]{geometry}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
  \hline
  & & Station T1 & & Station T2 \\
 & Observed-modeled & $|$observed-modeled$|$ & Observed-modeled & $|$observed-modeled$|$ \\ 
  \hline
Min. & -1.54 & 0.00 & -2.37 & 0.00 \\ 
  1st Qu. & 0.00 & 0.16 & -1.23 & 0.67 \\ 
  Median & 0.36 & 0.54 & -0.62 & 1.10 \\ 
  Mean & 0.86 & 1.00 & -0.21 & 1.08 \\ 
  3rd Qu. & 1.65 & 1.65 & 0.74 & 1.41 \\ 
  Max. & 5.54 & 5.54 & 5.05 & 5.05 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How can I make `station t1` and `Station T2` to get centered ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\multicolum`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations}
\usepackage[top=0.5in,bottom=1in,left=0.5in,right=0.4in]{geometry}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
  \hline
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Station T1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Station T2} \\
 & Observed-modeled & $|$observed-modeled$|$ & Observed-modeled & $|$observed-modeled$|$ \\ 
  \hline
Min. & -1.54 & 0.00 & -2.37 & 0.00 \\ 
  1st Qu. & 0.00 & 0.16 & -1.23 & 0.67 \\ 
  Median & 0.36 & 0.54 & -0.62 & 1.10 \\ 
  Mean & 0.86 & 1.00 & -0.21 & 1.08 \\ 
  3rd Qu. & 1.65 & 1.65 & 0.74 & 1.41 \\ 
  Max. & 5.54 & 5.54 & 5.05 & 5.05 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you are working with decimal values, perhaps you could be interested in the [`dcolumn`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) or [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) packages. Also, [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) will make your tables look better.

Answer (score 6):

[image: MWE]

For better results in the rules, use the package `booktabs`. The headers could be centered by using `\multicolumn`. Adding a middle blank column could be a good idea to allow some spacing between stations, so it is possible to add separate rule under each head.

On the other hand, IMHO the columns looks better centered than aligned to the right because the long  subheaders, but  certainly the best align will be center the decimal point. In this example this is made with  `dcolumn` package, but note that subheaders must have another alignment. This is not a big problem, since you can use, for example, `\multicolumn`  also for single cells.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[top=0.5in,bottom=1in,left=0.5in,right=0.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,tipa}
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{-1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lddcdd}
\toprule
 &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Station T1} & 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Station T2} \\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{5-6}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Observed-modeled} 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textpipe\,Observed-modeled\,\textpipe} & 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Observed-modeled} 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textpipe\,Observed-modeled\,\textpipe} \\ 
\midrule
Min.    & -1.54 & 0.00 & & -2.37 & 0.00 \\ 
1st Qu. &  0.00 & 0.16 & & -1.23 & 0.67 \\ 
Median  &  0.36 & 0.54 & & -0.62 & 1.10 \\ 
Mean    &  0.86 & 1.00 & & -0.21 & 1.08 \\ 
3rd Qu. &  1.65 & 1.65 & &  0.74 & 1.41 \\ 
Max.    &  5.54 & 5.54 & &  5.05 & 5.05 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```